# How can I make this code work on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, create-table

I was wondering why my SQL code isn't working properly on SQL Server while when I upload it on phpmyadmin it works perfectly. Is it some difference between those SQL's? Is someone able to make this code working well on SQL Server? I've posted only part of database but with your help I'll get done the rest.

```
create database Biblioteka;

use Biblioteka;

create table Autorzy
(
    ID_Autora int(5) Primary Key auto_increment,
    Imie varchar(25),
    Nazwisko varchar(25)
);

create table Czytelnicy
(
    ID_Czytelnika int(3) Primary Key auto_increment,
    ID_Klasy int(3),
    Imie varchar(25),
    Nazwisko varchar(25),
    PESEL char(11)
);

create table Klasa
(
    ID_Klasy int(3) Primary Key auto_increment,
    Nazwa_Klasy varchar(5)
);

alter table Czytelnicy
add foreign key (ID_Klasy) references Klasa(ID_Klasy);

insert into Autorzy values('','Stefan','Batory');
insert into Autorzy values('','Gabriela','Zapolska');
insert into Autorzy values('','Joanne','Rowling');

insert into Czytelnicy values('','1','Adam','Nowak','97091309264');
insert into Czytelnicy values('','2','Anna','Kowalczyk','99062312546');
insert into Czytelnicy values('','2','Jan','Dabrowski','77022610926');

insert into Klasa values('','1A');
insert into Klasa values('','2B');
insert into Klasa values('','3C');
```

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two different databases, whose SQL dialect is different. You cannot expect a MySQL script to work as-is in SQL Server.

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Your code would probably not run on MySQL: I would expect that inserting an empty string in an auto-incremented column would fail.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of errors. Firstly it says that database 'name' does not exist and I have to execute only 1 line of that code. When it is created it says "Incorrect syntax near 'auto_increment'." When I deal with it, it has another problem with int's..

Comment: *Every* RDBMS has a different dialect of SQL. SQL Server uses T-SQL (Transact SQL), where as MySQL uses its own version of SQL as well. When migrating from one RDBMS to another you have to (manually) translate from the dialect it was before to the new one. There is very little code that it transferable between RDBMS, as they all have different implementations. Even ISO SQL isn't supported by every RDBMS, and they all tend to support different amounts/parts of those standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starter, your original MySQL code has issues:

- inserting an empty string in an auto-incremented column is not supported; instead, you should not insert in that column, and let the database automatically assign a value to it (this requires explicitly listing the columns that you want to `insert` into, which is a best practice in SQL anyway)
- you need to `insert` in table `Klasa` first, *then* insert into referencing table `Czytelnicy`

When it comes to translating this to SQL Server:

- `auto_increment` is not supported; you can use `identity(1, 1)` instead
- the `int` does not accept a length

This would work:

```
create table Autorzy(
    ID_Autora int identity(1, 1) Primary Key,
    Imie varchar(25),
    Nazwisko varchar(25)
);

create table Czytelnicy(
    ID_Czytelnika int identity(1, 1) Primary Key,
    ID_Klasy int,
    Imie varchar(25),
    Nazwisko varchar(25),
    PESEL char(11)
);

create table Klasa(
    ID_Klasy int identity(1, 1)Primary Key,
    Nazwa_Klasy varchar(5)
);

alter table Czytelnicy
add foreign key (ID_Klasy) references Klasa(ID_Klasy);

insert into Autorzy(Imie, Nazwisko) values('Stefan','Batory');
insert into Autorzy(Imie, Nazwisko) values('Gabriela','Zapolska');
insert into Autorzy(Imie, Nazwisko) values('Joanne','Rowling');

insert into Klasa(Nazwa_Klasy) values('1A');
insert into Klasa(Nazwa_Klasy) values('2B');
insert into Klasa(Nazwa_Klasy) values('3C');

insert into Czytelnicy(ID_Klasy, Imie, Nazwisko, PESEL) values(1,'Adam','Nowak','97091309264');
insert into Czytelnicy(ID_Klasy, Imie, Nazwisko, PESEL) values(2,'Anna','Kowalczyk','99062312546');
insert into Czytelnicy(ID_Klasy, Imie, Nazwisko, PESEL) values(2,'Jan','Dabrowski','77022610926');
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8fc06c4288a7f0a76f2544b7421dd28a)**

Answer (score 0):

**I have changed the syntax to work with MS SQL Server.check the foreign key before insert new records**

```
create database Biblioteka;
go

use Biblioteka;

create table Autorzy(
ID_Autora  int Primary Key identity(1,1),
Imie varchar(25),
Nazwisko varchar(25));

create table Czytelnicy(
ID_Czytelnika int Primary Key identity(1,1),
ID_Klasy int,
Imie varchar(25),
Nazwisko varchar(25),
PESEL char(11));

create table Klasa(
ID_Klasy int Primary Key identity(1,1),
Nazwa_Klasy varchar(5));

alter table Czytelnicy
add foreign key (ID_Klasy) references Klasa(ID_Klasy);

insert into Autorzy values('Stefan','Batory');
insert into Autorzy values('Gabriela','Zapolska');
insert into Autorzy values('Joanne','Rowling');

insert into Czytelnicy values('1','Adam','Nowak','97091309264');
insert into Czytelnicy values('2','Anna','Kowalczyk','99062312546');
insert into Czytelnicy values('2','Jan','Dabrowski','77022610926');

insert into Klasa values('1A');
insert into Klasa values('2B');
insert into Klasa values('3C');
```